# Does 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem applicable in higher dimensions?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I want to know

> Does 2-dimensional Gauss-Bonnet theorem applicable (any topological or geometrical obstruction) in higher dimensions?

My idea is that one can consider 2-dimensional embedded sub-manifolds of $(M^n,g)$ and then applying Gauss-Bonnet theorem to all of such sub-manifolds then gluing them together somehow and finding a topological or geometrical property. Is that possible at all?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but it sure makes a good question.  You might take it to MathOverflow.  ***+1, endorsed!***

Comment: Can I post it at MO today or should I wait days then if nobody responded my question I post it at MO?

Comment: I don't know the protocol. Sorry. Who knows, you might get a good answer here.  Cheers!

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want a generalization of Gauss-Bonnet, or do you want to use it (in its $2-$dimensional formulation) to deduce a higher dimensional result? Because for the former you might look up something like the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis: I know about Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.I want to use 2−dimensional Gauss-Bonnet to deduce a higher dimensional result.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but what kind of result do you have in mind? I think it seems hard to glue together these submanifolds to get a good result, since these submanifolds should be measure zero in $M^n$ when $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis: You might right, but a loop has measure zero in $M^n$ and it represent the fundamental group of $M$.

Comment: This has been [crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361399/does-2-dimensional-gauss-bonnet-theorem-applicable-in-higher-dimensions)

Comment: I think the question has an interesting kernel but needs to be dramatically refined before it can be answered with anything more than a vague wave toward the literature of a particular subfield.